# Search Strings for Wildcard in python and return position of match

Tags: python, regex, string, search

I am currently dealing with a dataset that is composed of thousands of strings with identities and would like to search for the positions at which a wildcard motif (which is composed of an N followed by any letter besides P and then an S or a T) occurs within the stringusing  the RegEx module and return a list of IDs pair with the positions at which the motif occurs.

```
import re
strings = [['ID#1','NTGSLTKNASMNLTQRSNQT'],['ID#2','NLSHTNWEUWBNTTDKWODNUT'],...]
for x in strings:
    re.search('N[^P][ST]',x[1])
```

Which I would like to return:

```
[['ID#1',[8,12,18]],['ID#2',[1,12,20]],.....]
```

If anyone has any ideas it would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely looking for this instead.

```
re.finditer(pattern, string[, flags])
```

Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

This will work..

```
import re

strings = [['ID#1','NTGSLTKNASMNLTQRSNQT'],['ID#2','NLSHTNWEUWBNTTDKWODNUT']]
pattern = re.compile('N[^P][ST]')

print [[f[0], [m.start() + 1 for m in pattern.finditer(f[1])]] for f in strings]
```

or you could possibly try something like..

```
import re

strings = [['ID#1','NTGSLTKNASMNLTQRSNQT'],['ID#2','NLSHTNWEUWBNTTDKWODNUT']]
pattern = re.compile('N[^P][ST]')

for x in strings:
    p = pattern.finditer(x[1])
    print [[x[0], [m.start() + 1 for m in p]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced in Python, but I think you can do something like this:

```
import re
strings = [['ID#1','NTGSLTKNASMNLTQRSNQT'],['ID#2','NLSHTNWEUWBNTTDKWODNUT']]
def findpos(s):
    return [s[0], [m.start() + 1 for m in re.finditer('N[^P][ST]',s[1])]]

return map(findpos, strings)
// [['ID#1', [8, 12, 18]], ['ID#2', [1, 12, 20]]]
```

or even more simply, just:

```
[[s[0], [m.start() + 1 for m in re.finditer('N[^P][ST]',s[1])]] for s in strings]
```